# note passed in as part of CreateCheckoutRequest, but where to on the payment page or the dashboard to view them?

Tags: square-connect

I am using nodeJs, and I have passed in note inside [CreateCheckoutRequest](https://github.com/square/connect-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/docs/CreateCheckoutRequest.md), however, i am not seeing the note showing on the payment page url generated by [createCheckout](https://github.com/square/connect-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/docs/CheckoutApi.md#createCheckout) or the dashboard page.
My ultimate goal is our frontend can pass in the phone number as note to sqaure-connect, so that we can view the phonenumber from our dashboard once the customer completes an order

Tried to look at old transactions, since we didnt use note, didnt see any note.

```
    const checkout = SquareConnect.CreateCheckoutRequest.constructFromObject({
      idempotency_key: 'sample_key,
      order: orderRequest,
      redirect_url: redirect_url,
      ask_for_shipping_address: true
      note, // need to see it from dashboard once the user completes an order
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding a `note` to a [CreateCheckout](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-checkout-createcheckout) request, it will end up on the `tenders->note` field of the associated transaction. To clarify, once the customer has paid on the checkout page, it should redirect to your web page (based on your `redirect_url` field that you passed to `CreateCheckout` originally). From there, the url will contain a parameter called `transaction_id`. You can then use this id to [retrieve the transaction](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-transactions-retrievetransaction) and digging into it to find the note (`transaction->tenders[0]->note`). In this particular use case, there will always only be one tender since Checkout doesn't allow multiple tenders.

Now, to actually answer your question: the tender note will be displayed as the main text you see when you view your transactions. So when you login to your Square Dashboard and click Transactions, in the main list, the "header" will be whatever the tender note was.